# Optimize Dockerfile to have a cached layer

Tags: docker

I'm struggling to have a setup that would be faster as the current one takes a huge amount of time.

The stage that I think could be optimized sadly is bellow the `COPY` directive. As far as I understood from the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/)  everything after `COPY` need to be run again.

But logically, for my case, what happens just after (two or three lines) will always produce the same results (but go tell Docker, ...).

Any workaround this ?

My susceptible part of Dockerfile:

```
RUN chmod +x $HOME/.cargo/env
RUN source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
RUN curl https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-pack/installer/init.sh -sSf | sh

COPY . .

RUN wasm-pack build --target nodejs /usr/src/app/pr/examples/wasm/
RUN npm pack /usr/src/app/pr/examples/wasm/pkg
RUN npm i pr-wasm-demo-0.1.0.tgz
```

Note: It is the *wasm-pack build* that takes time here. Also I cannot build it outside the image in host, as it is a different environment.

Comment: your question is unclear, does wasm-pack build require any files you copied during the copy layer? whatever files are needed have to be copied before, its as simple as that.

Comment: ofc. It does need them. but they are not changed in between, and never change between builds. but Docker never knows, I can get it.
imagine I can version the folder in host to be copied and built, probably this would be something Docker would somehow understand. all these are speculations. I'm no docker expert.

Comment: the only reason docker would run the wasm-pack AGAIN is if something changed in any of the files in the previous step or on a new system with no cache.